# How to transfer Steam and/or Skyrim to another PC without drivers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, pc

My school has restrictions on the computers, pretty much just not having access to admin stuff, and I want to put Skyrim from Steam onto my laptop. I can download anything to a hard drive and download it across, but it can't be something that uses drivers, like Steam setup. So I need instructions on what to download and copy across to get a working version of Skyrim on my other computer without downloading any apps that can 'Make changes to my device'.

Comment: If Steam cannot be installed on your school's PC then you cannot start Skyrim even if you managed to copy it to your school's PC because of copy protection, AFAIK.

Comment: Hmm, interesting challenge :)

Comment: @Skye-AT I sort of realized that would be the case, however, I think I might be able to transfer steam as well. The reason I believe this is possible is that they don't actually stop us from having programs like steam, just programs like the installer for steam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about installing a game on a school provided computer.  See https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7738/1351 for similar rational for closing these types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a DVD version of Skyrim will need Steam to activate (as discussed [here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/350543389013689240)). The best you can get out of a DVD is reducing downloads to updates (if you follow [specific instructions](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/4566-6D94-3A46-953A)).

So **no**, unless you are able to install Steam itself, you will not be able to run Skyrim on that PC.

Comment: That's correct, I want to get them both, I cant use the steam downloader to get steam but I may be able to transfer steam itself to my other computer using the harddrive.

Comment: Steam is not a portable app, you would still need admin permissions to make it work (and therefore be able to activate games).